# Print Facelets parameters in xhtml page

Tags: java, jsf-2, facelets

Is there anyway to print the values of facelets' parameters such as "facelets.DEVELOPMENT" (configured in web.xml) in a xhtml page?

PS.: I would like to print these values even if they're not in web.xml. In these cases it would print the setted default values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** reference all Facelets-specific parameters in EL directly, even not the defaults, but you can reference all context parameters in EL. They're available by the [implicit EL object](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects) `#{initParam}` which basically references [`ExternalContext#getInitParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getInitParameterMap%28%29).

So, if you know the parameter name beforehand, this should do:

```html
<p>
    Value of facelets.DEVELOPMENT context param: 
    #{initParam['facelets.DEVELOPMENT']}
</p>
```

Or if you just want to display all context params:

```html
<dl>
    <c:forEach items="#{initParam}" var="p">
        <dt>#{p.key}</dt>
        <dd>#{p.value}</dd>
    </c:forEach>
</dl>
```

Note that [`<c:forEach>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/c/forEach.html) is used because [`<ui:repeat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) doesn't support maps. If you however really need a view render time component and not a view build time tag, then you can also use `<ui:repeat>`, provided that EL 2.2 is supported in your environment:

```html
<dl>
    <ui:repeat value="#{initParam.entrySet().toArray()}" var="p">
        <dt>#{p.key}</dt>
        <dd>#{p.value}</dd>
    </ui:repeat>
</dl>
```

Either way, in order to filter specifically Facelets parameters, check if `#{p.key}` doesn't start with `"facelets."` using [`#{fn:startsWith()}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/fn/startsWith.fn.html) and so on.

```html
<ui:fragment rendered="#{fn:startsWith(p.key, 'facelets.')}">
    <dt>#{p.key}</dt>
    <dd>#{p.value}</dd>
</ui:fragment>
```

---

**Update** as per the comments, you seem to be more interested in specifically the JSF project stage (which is in JSF2 normally to be set by `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` context parameter by the way, the `facelets.DEVELOPMENT` is specific to old Facelets 1.x). This is just available by [`Application#getProjectStage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getProjectStage%28%29) as follows:

```
#{facesContext.application.projectStage}
```

To specifically check if JSF is in development stage, just do

```html
<ui:fragment rendered="#{facesContext.application.projectStage == 'Development'}">
    <div class="warning">JSF is running in development stage!</div>
</ui:fragment>
```

Again, for an overview of all implicit EL objects, check the link in the 1st paragraph.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. But I need these values even if I omit them in web.xml. For example, I need to know if facelets.DEVELOPMENT is set to true or false but I didn't set it in web.xml.

Comment: The project stage is just available by `#{facesContext.application.projectStage}`. You can just check if it equals `Development` or not. Note that `facelets.Development` is specific to Facelets 1.x, not to JSF 2.x (which you seem to be using as per the question tags), it should be `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE`.

Comment: But what about the other config values such as `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` or `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING`?

Comment: You know the default values before deploy. You know how to find out specific context params in EL (via e.g. `#{initParam['javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD']}`). Just do the math.